# Which salat (namaz) among the five times in a day to be performed silently?

Tags: salat, practical-islam

Which  salat (namaz) among the five times in a day  to be performed silently?

Comment: what you mean by namaz

Comment: This question is too basical it should have been answered several times on the site. Please do some research effort and you'll find answers. See for example [How to lead prayer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16969/how-to-be-a-proper-imam-in-a-congregation-of-fardhu-correctly-leading-of-praye), [Proof to pray dhuhr and 'asr silently](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24495/what-is-the-proof-to-pray-dzuhur-asr-silently-allah-in-al-quran-says-17-110) and [Meaning of silent recitation](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/55474/what-is-the-meaning-of-reciting-silently)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zuhr and Asr are to be performed silently in the means of that the Imam does not recite the Quran loudly to where the congregation can hear it.